# JSON data insert sqLit Database not working

Tags: android, sql, json, sqlite, cordova

I tried to `JSON` data insert into `SqLit` database in **PhoneGap**. I created a table with two columns, like this:

```
function setup(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HEADER_DATA');
    tx.executeSql("create table if not exists bookinformation(inserkey TEXT, key TEXT)");
}
```

This code runs successfully and the table is created. Then, I insert JSON data into the `bookinformation` table, like this:

```
function dbReady() {
db.transaction(function(tx) {
        alert("5");
        $.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two',function(data){
         $.each(data, function(i, dat){
         tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO bookinformation (inserkey, key) VALUES("'+data.one+'", "'+data.key+'")');    
        alert("completed");
    });
});     
    }, errorHandler, function() { alert('added row'); });
}
```

However, the insert statement fails. I get this error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError:Failed to execute 'executeSql' on 'SQLTransaction':SQL execution is disallowed
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

*Old question but this might help others.*

That error is usually caused by the transaction `tx` being stale.

This is because of the ajax call and by the time your ajax callback gets hit that `tx` object is no longer valid. The same happens if you use `setTimeout` or any time consuming non-Websql operation aswell.

To avoid that simply, create the transaction inside in the callback.

E.g

```
function dbReady() {
    $.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two',function(data) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            alert("5");
            $.each(data, function(i, dat) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO bookinformation (inserkey, key) VALUES("'+data.one+'", "'+data.key+'")');
            });
            alert("completed");
        }, errorHandler, function() { alert('added row'); });
    });
}
```