# Jquery wait for return of JSON object before executeSQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web-sql

In the following function, how can I tell JS to wait for the return of my ajax call before proceeding with sql transaction.
The following sample code currently get the data properly, but the sql transaction is executed before the AJAX call populate my `employees []`

I try to place sql operation after succes but I got the following error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'executeSql' on 'SQLTransaction': SQL execution is disallowed.
```

Here is part of the code

```
var addSampleData = function (tx, employees) {

        var employees = [];

$.ajax({
            url: 'my-path-to-my-json-answer',
            success: function (value, status) {
            employees.push(value);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, exception) {
            console.log("Connection with the server fail.\n" + textStatus + 'status is: ' + exception);
        }
    });

        var l = employees.length;

        var sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO leaderboard " +
        "(id, uFname, uLname, uRegion, uCountry, uScore) " +
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        var e;

        for (var i = 0; i < l; i = i + 1) {
            e = employees[i];
            tx.executeSql(sql, [e.id, e.uFname, e.uLname, e.uRegion, e.uCountry, e.uScore],
                function () {
                    console.log('INSERT success');
                },
                function (tx, error) {
                    console.log('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
                });
        }   

    }
```

Any suggestion to improve that code are welcome.

Comment: Use `.done` search jquery for promise syntax

Comment: trigger the SQL call from your "success" function (either code directly in the function, or put in a call to another function which runs the query). This callback is only executed once the response is received from the server. Ajax is asynchronous. Conceptually, you can't "tell other code to wait", you can simply "not execute it until ajax is finished" - and the only way to do that is through the "success" callback (or via .done() if you use the Promise interface).

Comment: In addition to the above: Why do you re-define parameter employee? You should also consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142680/json-data-insert-sqlit-database-not-working), depending on how your entire application behaves.

Comment: good point @Ceredig, the employees var should not be passed as a parameter in the function. Code works now, since I execute my websql transaction after success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because Ajax calls are asynchronous and browser starts a separate thread for the ajax call. In order to execute your SQL query after ajax call completion, put the code you want to SQL query code in success method of ajax as below...

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {action: 'submit_data', info: info},
        success: function(data) {
            //do your SQL work here...
            console.log('doing SQL work');
        },
        error: function(data) {
           console.log('boo...boo...');
        },
    });
```